# How to disable options menu for landscape view?

Tags: java, android, menu, android-2.2-froyo, options-menu

I have an options menu, but don't want it to appear when the screen is flipped horizontal. I have the following method to determine lanscape, but need to know how to disable the options menu.

```
private boolean isLandscape() {
        if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
  return !isLandscape();
}
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: only use a Portrair orientation. :D